# Opening PDF previews with Chrome on an Optiplex 7010 or 7000 results in a grey square in the preview pane

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, pdf

As the title states. Opening PDF previews with Chrome on an Optiplex 7010 or 7000 results in a grey square in the preview pane.

Notes:

1. This issue does not occur for any other Optiplex series (5060, 7090, 7070, etc)
2. On all series, including the 7010 or the 7000, the PDF preview works fine in Edge.
3. No issues simply downloading the PDF and open with > adobe acrobat DC
4. Nothing in group policy is denying this

Specs:

1. Windows 10 enterprise 21H2
2. Chrome version: 120.0.6099.200
3. Edge version: 120.0.2210.121
4. Adobe version: Acrobat DC 23.008.20421

Thoughts?

Comment: Looks like you've done considerable trouble-shooting yourself, testing multiple machines and browsers! Off hand, I assume there is a compatibility issue in Chrome browser on those models, perhaps a video driver issue, and I'd tell users to use another browser, whether Edge, which you've tested, or Brave, Firefox or another, unless there's a compelling reason to fix that external issue.